# MS word 2013 wildcard: how to remove parenthesis but keep the text inside?

Tags: ms-word, wildcard

If there is a duplicate, I could not find it (so I'm probably not the only one...)

Answer (score 1):

This will remove the parenthesis without deleting the text inside (wildcard must be checked)

**find:**

```
\((*)\)
```

**replace:**

```
\1
```